# Matrix row addition inside NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I'm using `NDSolve` and my variables are matrix elements so that the equations to be solved are in matrix form. Here is the MWE

```
ClearAll;
\[Mu]1 = 1.;
time = 10;
n = 2; 
m = 2; 
m1 = Table[If[i == j, i, 0], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
m2 = Table[If[i == j - 1, Sqrt[j], 0], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
m3 = Table[If[i == j + 1, Sqrt[j + 1], 0], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
{d1, d2} = {{{0.0769231, 0}, {0, 1.}}, {{7.2111, 0}, {0, 2.}}}

(*initial conditions*)
p0 = Normalize@Table[If[i == 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, m}];
x0 = Normalize@Table[If[i == 1, 1, 0], {i, 1, m}];
initc = a[0] == x0 + I*p0;
initq = c[0] == 
   Table[If[i == 1 && j == 0, 1, 0], {i, 1, m}, {j, 0, n}];

(*setup differential equations*)
sol = 
 NDSolve[{a'[
     t] == -I (\[Mu]1^2*d2.a[t] + 
       1/2 d2.d1.Total[((c[t].(m2 + m3))*c[t]), {2}]), 
   c'[t] == -I (c[t].m1 + Re[a[t]].d1 *(c[t].Transpose[(m2 + m3)])), 
   initc, initq}, {a, c}, {t, 0, time}]
```

The `NDSolve` in this example does not evaluate at all. It evaluates if I remove the second term in the first equation (i.e. the term with `1/2 d2.d1.Total`) which makes me think that this operation is not being performed for some reason. I have tried doing this with `Plus` instead of `Total` and it still doesn't work.

What's going wrong and how can this be done?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your equations; did you really intend `((c[t].(m2 + m3))*c[t])` to be a Hadamard product?

Comment: `ClearAll` doesn't do anything on its own. Replace it with `ClearAll["Global`*"]` (this will clear everything, so make sure that you do not have anything in memory that you want to retain). Your code executes and returns an answer from `NDSolve`. Have you tried restarting MMA?

Comment: I'm not sure what Hadamard product means but the first product is a matrix product and the second one is a direct multiplication. That is intentional

Comment: @MarcoB Yes I have used `Global` and have tried restarting but that doesn't help me. I'm not sure how this is executing for you. when I run it, it just returns the expanded `NDSolve` without actually solving anything

Comment: MMA version 13.0.1. I get a solution. Try with a new kernel.

Comment: @DanielHuber I'm on 11.3 and this doesn't give a solution even with a new kernel. Perhaps I need to upgrade